is my solution correct to a Monty hall variation with 4 doors?
Problem:
You've participated in a new type of "Who Wants to Be a Millionaire?" quiz. The last question worth 1,000,000 euros is remaining. The question is difficult, and you have no idea what the correct answer is. There are four answer options, and only one is correct. You guess and choose option A. Then, the machine eliminates one definitely incorrect answer from the remaining three options. Now there are three options left: your chosen A and two others. The host asks, "Do you want to switch your answer?"
Should you switch your answer?
My solution:
Yes, you should switch.
We have a $3/4$ chance that our first choice is false. The only way to win after swapping is if our first choice is false. And in that case, the machine removes one other choice that is also false, so in the other 2 that are left (in addition to my false selection), one of them is correct. So if we now swap, we have a $1/2$ chance of picking the correct one.
So, swapping after winning requires that our first choice is false (3/4 chance) and that we pick the correct one when swapping ($1/2$ chance), so the probability is $(3/4) \cdot (1/2) = 0.375$.
Our chances of winning if we didn't swap are $1/4$, which is less than $0.375$, so yes you should swap.

Is that a correct answer? I'm not sure of the probability calculations if I got everything correct.

Not switching wins iff you originally guessed right , this is a 1/4 chance. If you switch , you have a chance of 1/2 , if you guessed wrong originally , this chance is therefore 3/4*1/2=3/8. If you guessed right originally , switching loses. Hence , your analysis is correct.
